# cassandra : Is there a way to get all value of columns starting with a particular prefix?

Tags: java, cassandra, hector, cassandra-0.7

I need to get all column:column_value pairs for a key.
the constraint is columns have a common Prefix , is there a way to get it using Hector ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do a SliceQuery, and do a range from the prefix to prefix|, providing its only alphanumerics that should work.

```
StringSerializer ss = StringSerializer.get();
SliceQuery sliceQuery = HFactory.createSliceQuery(keySpace, rowSerializer, ss, ss);
sliceQuery.setColumnFamily(MY_COLUMN_FAMILY);
sliceQuery.setKey(rowKey);
sliceQuery.setRange("prefix", "prefix|", false, Integer.MAX_INT);
```

Comment: There is no range , i just want all coluns with the prefixes , but i also think it will be too slow right as cassandra will have to iterate over all columns ?

Comment: Not exactly, it keeps an index of the columns every so many bytes (column_index_size_in_kb).  Since the columns are sorted it will be able to jump pretty close (within the size of the index above) to the data and read until it reaches the end of the slice.  Your column slice would actually be fast and efficient.  Think of it as a binary search to the data, then reading it until it reaches the "prefix|" value.